# jquery - populate data in tinymce inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm working on a laravel 5.4 app where i've included the tinymce plugin so as to add content. this is working fine. This content is then saved in a database and listed on a html table and it can be edited or deleted(normal crud)

issue is on clicking on the edit button, the modal pops up but the textarea with the tinymce content is blank. below is the jquery handling this bit and also the function handling the tinymce:

```
$(function(){
    $('.edit-subchapter').on('click', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("value");
        $.get('subchapters/edit/'+id, function(response){
           for (var i in response) 
            {
                console.log(response[i].content);
                $("#formEdit #content").val(response[i].content);
            }
        },'json');
    });
});

var editor_config = {
path_absolute : "{{URL::to('/')}}/",
selector      : "textarea",
plugins: [
  "advlist autolink lists link image charmap hr anchor pagebreak",
   "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality"
],
menubar: false,
toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media"
};

tinymce.init(editor_config);
```

the weird part is that my `console.log(response[i].content);` is returning the data from the database so i know that bit is working

the problem seems when it is being passed to the textarea: `$("#formEdit #content").val(response[i].content);`, nothing is displayed. so this to the best of my understanding is a tinymce problem? what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. i figured it out. when setting a value in tinymce, we don't use the html controls as tinymce replaces the textarea at runtime.

so instead of this:

```
$("#formEdit #content").val(response[i].content);
```

we'll have this:

```
tinymce.get('content').setContent(response[i].content);
```

and after editing the value in the tinymce, to capture that value, instead of:

```
$("#formEdit #content").val();
```

we'll have:

```
tinymce.get('content').getContent();
```

Some nice reference sites here:

http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:How-to_load/save_with_Ajax_in_TinyMCE

[https://forums.asp.net/t/1825756.aspx?Set+value+of+textarea+tinymce+in+jQuery+](https://forums.asp.net/t/1825756.aspx?Set%20value%20of%20textarea%20tinymce%20in%20jQuery%20)

hope this will be helpful to anyone with a similar issue